# How to profile a Dart CLI app on Mac?

Tags: macos, dart, profiling

How to profile (CPU) Dart CLI apps on MacOSX? For Linux, I could use 'perf' as described there - https://code.google.com/p/dart/wiki/Profiling, but there is no 'perf' for MacOSX.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Observatory built into the VM might do what you need https://www.dartlang.org/tools/observatory/

Comment: Oh, I was under impression it's Dartium-only thing. Just tried it on CLI app - works perfectly, thanks!